# Weird condition for null space and range implying invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is:

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 \\ A_2\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ (an $n\times n$ matrix with entries on $\mathbb{C}$) and suppose that $\mathcal{N}(A_1)=\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)$ ($\mathcal{N}$ being the null space, and $\mathcal{R}$ the range). Prove that $A$ is invertible.

My thought process was, to prove that $A$ is invertible, it seems reasonable that from what we're given I'm gonna try to prove that $n(A)=0$ (the dimension of the null space of $A$ is $0$).

Well, we have that $\dim(\mathcal{N}(A))=\dim(\mathcal{N}(A_1)\cap\mathcal{N}(A_2))$, which is equal to $\dim(\mathcal{N}(A_1))+\dim(\mathcal{N}(A_2))-\dim(\mathcal{N}(A_1)+\mathcal{N}(A_2))$. By the hypothesis, $\mathcal{N}(A_1)=\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)$, and $\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)=\mathcal{R}(A_2)$, so  we're left with

$$\dim(\mathcal{N}(A))=n-\dim(\mathcal{N}(A_1)+\mathcal{N}(A_2))$$

but I can't find a way to justify why $\dim(\mathcal{N}(A_1)+\mathcal{N}(A_2))=n$, which is what it has to be if $A$ is invertible...

**Edit**: where $\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)=\mathcal{R}(A_2)$ is, it's actually meant to be $r(A_2)=r(A_2^\top)$ (the rank of these matrices is equal).

Comment: I think I've got it... aren't $\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)$ and $\mathcal{N}(A_2)$ orthogonal subspaces? The dimension of that sum would then be $n$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $A$ is not invertible. Then there exists a nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that 
$$0 = Av = \begin{bmatrix}A_1v \\ A_2v\end{bmatrix}.$$
This implies that $v \in \mathcal{N}(A_1)$ and $v \in \mathcal{N}(A_2)$. But then $v \in \mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)$, so there exists a vector $u$ such that $v = A_2^\top u$, and hence
$$0 \neq v^\top v = (A_2^\top u)^\top v = u^\top A_2 v = u^\top 0 = 0,$$
a contradiction. So the assumption cannot be true, and $A$ is therefore invertible.

Comment: That seems good, and way easier than what I did. Is my comment wrong, though?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me why 
$$\text{dim}(\mathcal{N}(A_1) \cap \mathcal{N}(A_2)) = \text{dim}(\mathcal{N}(A_1)) + \text{dim}(\mathcal{N}(A_2)) - \text{dim}(\mathcal{N}(A_1) + \mathcal{N}(A_2)).$$
It could be that I'm missing something obvious here.

Also, we will typically not have $\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top) = \mathcal{R}(A_2)$; indeed, since $A_2$ is not square, the length of the vectors in each of those spaces will not be the same.

Your comment on $\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)$ being orthogonal to $\mathcal{N}(A_2)$ is correct though.

Comment: The formula is for the dimension of the sum of two subspaces, it's well known (check 2.43 in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, for example, or this: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-dimension-of-a-sum-of-subspaces). The second part was my mistake, it's not $\mathcal{R}(A_2^\top)=\mathcal{R}(A_2)$ that I meant to say, but actually $r(A_2)=r(A_2^\top)$ (the rank of $A_2$ and its transpose is equal).